# By What Mechanism Does Heat Cause Muscle Relaxation?

Tags: muscles, blood-circulation, heat

Heat is commonly used "loosen" muscles, but what exactly is happening to relax the muscle? It wouldn't make sense that increased blood flow alone would relax muscle.

Answer (score 1):

Read this it was very helpful to me as a Reiki Practitioner who wants to know how the heat generated by my hands on therapy with my patients for Hospice brings such relaxation to them.
http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/effects-temperature-muscular-contraction-11504.html

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer. Your answer may become invalid if the link expires or gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

**There may not be one because it may not have any effect.**

It appears to be a placebo effect. There is not a lot of clinical evidence heat does [anything beneficial](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00421-004-1153-y), in fact cold may actually be more [effective](http://www.jospt.org/doi/abs/10.2519/jospt.1982.3.3.133?code=jospt-site). Evidence of an effect appears to be mostly anecdotal or unscientific "studies".